# Any idea ? Warning assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have it like this

My struct looks like this

```
typedef struct something
{
   int randomData;
   int **array;
}SOMETHING;
```

array is allocated

```
SOMETHING *ANYTHING= calloc(sizeof(SOMETHING),sizeof(int));
ANYTHING->array = calloc(someSizeParamater,sizeof(SOMETHING));
int key = 5;
```

in a code where I wish to do that into `array[index]` I put some value of int :

```
ANYTHING->array[index]=key;
```

but it says given error, any idea how to fix this ? compiler retypes it on its own but I would like know to how to assign the value to struct correctly.

Once I do `ANYTHING->array[0][index] = key;` program crashes and does not work properly as it works with given warning.

Comment: Do not update a question in comment The question has an "edit"-button. Add updates as updates by edting the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here is your "First Post Review": (1) Please annotate more explicitly which line is referenced by the unexpected warning - is it the last of your code snippets? (2) Does `looks +- like this` mean that there is a substantial difference (not good!), or that you only stripped unnecessary detail to create a minimal example (good!) ? (3) In your code snippets, please apply a consistent coding style (whitespaces around operators etc.).

Answer (score 0):

`array` is typed `int**`, which is a pointer (namely to another pointer, to a pointer to `int`).

The `[]`-operator dereferences (once).

So doing `array[...]` evaluates to what `array` points to, which is, as mentioned above `int*`, to which your code tries to assign an `int` here:

> ```
> ANYTHING->array[index]=key;
> ```

You mostly never want to assign an `int` to an `int*`, to a pointer to `int`.

Comment: ANYTHING->array[index]=key; is already there and it gives given warning I wish to solve.

Comment: I am quoting your code as an example to my explanation before. Did you read my explanation? If it is not clear tell me what is unclear.

Comment: Well once I do ANYTHING->array[0][index] = key; program crashes and does not work properly as it works with given warning. So would you be able to tell me how to retype the given int to correct form ?

Comment: ANYTHING->array[index]=(int *)key; this gives me another error [Warning] cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Comment: Why do you declare `array` as an `int**` in the first place? Why not just define it as `int*`?

Comment: Well since I am doing hashing function and I need to use it like this, it is correct since I store pointers to array.

Comment: Casting  (`... =(int *)key`) just tries to solve the problem by trying to hide it.

Comment: Pointers need to point some where before you can write to where they point. You miss to allocated memory to where the pointers your code does allocate point to.

Comment: well the compiler manages to solve it correctly because when I try to reach given index at array[i] it gives me correct key, I just need syntax to rewrite it correctly, so it does not give me an warning

Comment: so what's the solution here ? I can show you whole source but I cannot make it public, for various and such reasons

Comment: Best describe the problem you want to solve in more detail. As it stands it is not clear what you finally want to achieve. All we know is that you try something which cannot work.

Comment: I have a struct where I have allocted an array, in array I would like to place to indexes given keys. Thats what I would like to achieve.